# django rest framework serialize the related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="category")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ProductVariation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="product")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductVariantSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariation

        fields = (
            "name",
            )

class CategoryDetailSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):

    product_variant = PromotionVariantSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields =(
            "name",
            "product_variant" #how can i do this
            )
```

here i want to list  all the product variant that belongs to the category.
can i do this way or i want to write methods to get the product variant details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to write serializers for `Product` and `ProductVariation` models. You can't display the `ProductVariation` objects right in the `Category` model serializer, as there is no direct relation between `Category` and `ProductVariation` models. But you could try may be using separate nested serializers for `Product` and `ProductVariation` models.

```
class ProductVariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariation
        fields = ("name", )

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = ProductVariantSerializer(source='product', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'variants')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(source='category', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'products')
```

You could use the `CategorySerializer` for nested relationships.

Comment: how can i display only the variant not the products.

Comment: Then, you may need to use serializer method field or such approach, because `Category` and `ProductVariation` are related only through `Product` model.